# Loop through an array of objects and create a new object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, each object has a title, content and contentHTML. I want to map over this array and create a new object. The new object will take the value of the title property and use this as the parent property for each of the content and contentHTML properties. The code below only seems to be getting the last object in the array.

**The results is:**

```
{
  "sidebar": {
      "text": "Some sidbar text here",
      "content": "<p>Some sidebar text here</p>"
    }
}
```

**The expected result is:**

```
{
    header: {
        text: "Some header text here",
        content: "<p>Some header text here</p>"
    },
    footer: {
        text: "Some footer text here",
        content: "<p>Some footer text here</p>"
    },
    sidebar: {
        text: "Some sidbar text here",
        content: "<p>Some sidebar text here</p>"
    }
}
```

```js
var originalObj = [{
    title: "header",
    content: "Some header text here",
    contentHTML: "<p>Some header text here</p>"
  },
  {
    title: "footer",
    content: "Some footer text here",
    contentHTML: "<p>Some footer text here</p>"
  },
  {
    title: "sidebar",
    content: "Some sidbar text here",
    contentHTML: "<p>Some sidebar text here</p>"
  }
];
let newObject = {};
for (let item of originalObj) {
  var tempObj = {
    [item.title]: {
      text: item.content,
      content: item.contentHTML
    }
  };
  newObject = tempObj;
}
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting your object with new value every time you're doing

```
var tempObj = {//object keys}
```

Use spread operator to copy the previous values. Spread operator loops through objects iterable values and expands them.

```js
var originalObj = [
    {
        title: "header",
        content: "Some header text here",
        contentHTML: "<p>Some header text here</p>"
    },
    {
        title: "footer",
        content: "Some footer text here",
        contentHTML: "<p>Some footer text here</p>"
    },
    {
        title: "sidebar",
        content: "Some sidbar text here",
        contentHTML: "<p>Some sidebar text here</p>"
    }
];

let newObject = {};
for (let item of originalObj) {
    newObject = {
        ...newObject,
        [item.title]: {
            text: item.content,
            content: item.contentHTML
        }
    };
}
console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Thanks you, what does ...tempObj do?

Comment: Unpacks the existing tempObj into the new tempObj - basically allows you to extend the object. Although personally I would've done something like `newObject[item.title] = {text:item.content, content:item.contentHTML};`

Comment: The `tempObj` is redundant. You can get the same result by replacing `tempObj` with `newObject` (next to `var` and the splat) and then you also don't need `newObject = tempObj;`

Answer (score 1):

This alternative uses the function `reduce` to build the desired output.

```js
var originalObj = [ {  title: "header",  content: "Some header text here",  contentHTML: "<p>Some header text here</p>" }, {  title: "footer",  content: "Some footer text here",  contentHTML: "<p>Some footer text here</p>" }, {  title: "sidebar",  content: "Some sidbar text here",  contentHTML: "<p>Some sidebar text here</p>" }],
    newObject = originalObj.reduce((a, {title, content: text, contentHTML: content} = obj) => {
      return Object.assign(a, {[title]: {text, content}});
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(newObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You were overriding `newObject` with the contents of `tempObj` it's much easier if you just write directly into `newObject` like this.

```js
var originalObj = [{
    title: "header",
    content: "Some header text here",
    contentHTML: "<p>Some header text here</p>"
  },
  {
    title: "footer",
    content: "Some footer text here",
    contentHTML: "<p>Some footer text here</p>"
  },
  {
    title: "sidebar",
    content: "Some sidbar text here",
    contentHTML: "<p>Some sidebar text here</p>"
  }
];
let newObject = {};
for (let item of originalObj) {
  newObject[item.title] = {
    text: item.content,
    content: item.contentHTML
  }
}
console.log(newObject);
```

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do something like this perhaps:

```js
var originalObj = [
 {
  title: "header",
  content: "Some header text here",
  contentHTML: "<p>Some header text here</p>"
 },
 {
  title: "footer",
  content: "Some footer text here",
  contentHTML: "<p>Some footer text here</p>"
 },
 {
  title: "sidebar",
  content: "Some sidbar text here",
  contentHTML: "<p>Some sidebar text here</p>"
 }
];

var output = originalObj.reduce((accumulator, ele) => {
  accumulator[ele['title']] = {'text': ele['content'], 'content': ele['contentHTML']}
  return accumulator;
}, {})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been answered but if it still helps:

```
var newObject = {};
for (let item of originalObj) {
      newObject[item.title] = {
      text: item.content,
      content: item.contentHTML
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a different example and wanted to answer more dynamically
firstly, getting how many unique values we can have for a property i.e,`res` array in this example
then, filtering the objects and pushing into an array that the object's property matches with each unique value of the `res` array
in the example the resultant object is  `resObj`

```js
let anArray = [{id: 1, name:"orange"},
{id: 2, name:"orange"},
{id: 3, name:"apple"},
{id: 4, name:"apple"},
{id: 5, name:"rusk"},
{id: 6, name:"grape"}]
let res =  [...new Set(anArray.map(item => item.name))];
let resObj = {};

let newObj = (item, arr) => {
    let resArr = [];
  
    anArray.map((obj) => {
     if(item == obj.name){
     resArr.push(obj)
     }
 })
 return resArr
}
resObject = Object.fromEntries(res.map((item) => [item, newObj(item, anArray) ]) )

 
console.log(resObject)
```